# Materialize framework margin between columns

Tags: html, css, margin, materialize

Materialize framework comes with strange layout (at least for me). I can't find any margin between columns.
This is my code:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s4">
      kerlos      
  </div>
  <div class="col s4">
      kerlos      
  </div>
  <div class="col s4">
      kerlos     
  </div>
</div> 
</div>
```

[And this is how it is look in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4OjC.jpg).

There are no margins between the columns!

Comment: There are no `margin`s, only `padding`s between columns — https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/blob/master/dist/css/materialize.css#L6704. What is your problem?

Comment: My problem is if i need to make three columns in a row each one has a solid background color, but i want margin between them, how to achieve that with materialize !?

Comment: You want the content to be padded... or you actually want WHITE space around each column? what is your desired solution

Comment: What is the actual problem that you are trying to solve? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have the same issue, with buttons in a grid. The Materialize Grid help page (https://materializecss.com/grid.html) seems to use border to produce the gap. Even that didn't work for me.

Answer (score 16):

I suggest you use a separate element inside a column, for example, `.col-content`:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/24xg2f9g/1/)

```css
body {
    color: white;
}

.blue {
    background: blue;
}

.black {
    background: black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s4">
            <div class="col-content blue">kerlos</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col s4">
            <div class="col-content black">kerlos</div> 
        </div>
        <div class="col s4">
            <div class="col-content blue">kerlos</div>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: This one actually solves your problem, Thanks, @sergey.

Answer (score 5):

Whitespace between `.col` blocks is implemented via padding in Materialize. So, `.col` elements are used for layout.

Just should place Your visual blocks as childrens of `.col` elements.

Example – https://jsfiddle.net/y2dahvg5/

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12 m6 xl4">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-content">
        <span class="card-title">Item</span>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col s12 m6 xl4">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-content">
        <span class="card-title">Item</span>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col s12 m6 xl4">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-content">
        <span class="card-title">Item</span>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Another items ... -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

None of these answers are actually answering your question. I know exactly what you mean. Materialize (unlike Boostrap) does not take into consideration that you will use a header or content area with a solid color, so it doesn't provide "margin-space" like Bootstrap:

```
<div class="col-md-6"><div style="background: blue;">blue</div></div>
<div class="col-md-6"><div style="background: blue;">blue</div></div>
```

That would produce a solid whitespace of about 15px between each margin, regardless of the number of columns you create. It also degrades nicely.

When others are telling you to just apply a blanket padding solution, they're forgetting that the column to the right of the page will also have a padding and therefore ruin the line of containers on the right side of the page.

I suggest using @media queries depending on how many columns

If there are only two columns, then you can set padding-right on ALL divs to 15px, but then for @media query of large screen, set nth-child(even) (all divs on the right side of the screen with a padding of 0px;.

Keep in mind this still makes the left-hand column 15pix **thinner** than the right column, and if you have uniform content, it will be noticeable.

In this sense, Materialize failed to provide a proper column layout white space solution (using padding instead of global margin-space) and Bootstrap is just better in this area. Good luck to you.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to use classes provided by the Materialize framework, it provides us with a class 'offset' to add margins between columns. For example you can use the following code to add margins. You can learn more about grids and offsets [here.](http://materializecss.com/grid.html)

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aakashcr7/3ptLs5nh/)

CSS

```
.green {
    background: green;
}
.black {
    background: black;
    color: #fff;
}
```

HTML

```
 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s3 offset-s1 green">
            kerlos
        </div>
        <div class="col s3 offset-s1 black">
            kerlos
        </div>
        <div class="col s3 offset-s1 green">
            kerlos
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you only have put a nested column. That will add a padding of .75rem each side. You should put your background in the nested column.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

As of Current Materializecss version, this is not the case.

I modified the html code for better visualization:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s4 teal">
      <span class="teal lighten-2">kerlos</span>      
  </div>
  <div class="col s4 red">
            <span class="teal lighten-2">kerlos</span>      

 </div>
  <div class="col s4 teal">
        <span class="teal lighten-2">kerlos</span>      
 </div>
</div> 
</div>
```

The Result will look like as below:
[image]

Now suppose you don't want the padding then you have to add `style="padding:0"`

Answer (score -1):

Try this CSS

```
.col {
  padding:20px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```